# SQL Error After Table Import/Export

Tags: mysql, opencart

Hey I am trying to export the product tables from one opencart store to another,but I have had some issues doing that.
The majority of tables had 0 problems to import/export,however the `product` table gives the following error.

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 37

Here is the code itself.

```
    CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `points` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_available` date NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `measurement_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maximum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cost` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `style` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the COMMENT at the last line:

```
   CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `points` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_available` date NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `measurement_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `maximum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cost` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `style` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> CREATE TABLE `product` (   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,   `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,   `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,   `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,   `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,   `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL,   `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',   `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',   `points` int(8) NOT NULL,   `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `date_available` date NOT NULL,   `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',   `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',   `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',   `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',   `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,   `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',   `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',   `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,   `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,   `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',   `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',   `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL,   `measurement_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `maximum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `cost` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',   `style` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

MariaDB []> select version();
+---------------------+
| version()           |
+---------------------+
| 10.1.10-MariaDB-log |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Comment: Already did that and I get error at the INSERT Statemant afterwards.

Comment: which client you are using. i have test and it works. on linux system you can try to get a new shell $ sh ; and rhe connect again like $ mysql -uXXXX -pxxxx -hxxxx DBname; and insert the query again

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are getting **error because you have not completed last line comment** code for "style" column do one of the below options:

**a) Add comment description**

```
`style` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT "comment description"
```

**b)remove comment description**

```
`style` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```